# Margin-top: auto not working with position absolute

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` elements, one of which has `position: absolute`. My goal is to position this div at the bottom of its parent by using `margin-top: auto`.

This approach to positioning the `div` works well without `position: absolute` (see snippet)

```css
.profileMain {
  display: flex;
}

.userInfo {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
}

.userPrints {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10em;
}

footer {
  height: 10em;
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profileMain">

  <div class="userInfo">
    <p>This div is bottom positioned</p>
  </div>

  <div class="userPrints">
    <p>This div has normal positioning</p>
  </div>

</div>

<footer></footer>
```

When `position: absolute` is added, `margin-top: auto` is ignored. (see snippet)

```css
.profileMain {
  display: flex;
}

.userInfoHolder{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

.userInfo {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
}

.userPrints {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10em;
}

footer {
  height: 10em;
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profileMain">

  <div class = "userInfoHolder">
    <p>This div retains the positioning</p>
  </div>

  <div class="userInfo">
    <p>This div is bottom positioned</p>
  </div>

  <div class="userPrints">
    <p>This div has normal positioning</p>
  </div>

</div>

<footer></footer>
```

Why doesn't this approach work with `position: absolute`? Is there an alternative approach I can use to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: you are already using flex, so why you need absolute position ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it has to do with scrolling. The div with absolute positioning actually has `position: fixed` until it hits the footer. Then resets to `position: absolute` once it his the footer, and should be positioned at the bottom of its parent.

Comment: try `bottom: 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should understand, when you add `position: absolute` the `margin-top: auto` property doesn't work. So to make it position to bottom of its parent element, you have to add `bottom: 0` property and `position: relative` to its parent element. Try update your code like this.

```
.profileMain {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.userInfo {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

The answer for 'why?' is, when you apply position:absolute to any element, that element starts floating above all other elements simply like a different layer. As such, the element with position:absolute can't render the margin-top: auto property as it won't find the corresponding edge as of from where it should apply the auto value for margin-top property. I guess, this makes it a bit clear on the 'why?'

Comment: The answer for 'why?' is, when you apply position:absolute to any element, that element starts floating above all other elements simply like a different layer. As such, the element with position:absolute can't render the margin-top: auto property as it won't find the corresponding  edge as of from where it should apply the auto value for margin-top property. I guess, this makes it a bit clear on the 'why?'

Comment: and you should include this in your answer then ;)

Comment: included the answer to 'why?' in my answer :)